# DynamoDB Descending Order fetch records

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

i have 100 records in collection,

collection name:'users'

```
{
   "name":'senthilkumar',  
   "email":'senthily88@gmail.com',  //HashKey
   "age":21,
   "created":1465733486137,         //RangeKey-timestamp
}
```

i need to fetch records the following sql query wise

```
select * from users order by created desc limit 10
```

How i can get above query format records from **DynamoDB**

Answer (score 46):

Dynamodb sorts the results by the range key attribute. You can set the `ScanIndexForward` boolean parameter to `true` for ascending or `false` for descending.

resource: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

> Use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to provide a specific value
>   for the partition key. The Query operation will return all of the
>   items from the table or index with that partition key value. You can
>   optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a
>   sort key value and a comparison operator in KeyConditionExpression.
>   You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward
>   or reverse order, by sort key.

Comment: Yes, true = ascending, false = descending.

Comment: Thank you reply,  can i get sample example like CreateTable structure & fetch order by records Json format please,    i was try many more way but can't get descending order result,   i know my create table structure is wrong, kinldy please provide   **Create Table Json** & **Fetch Records** Query Format example please

Comment: Hey, were you able to get the records in descending order? I am facing a similar issue here.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The OP wants to return all rows. This answer is for returning a specific subset of all of the rows by a specific unique ID.

Answer (score 5):

**To Save Json Data to DynamoDB us put()**

```
var Newparams = {
    TableName: this.SuffleTableName,
       Item: {
        "userId": /* YOUR PRIMARY KEY */,
        "addedAt": /* YOUR SORT KEY */,
        "status": /* Additional Datas */,
       }
}
```

**Fetch Data From DynamoDB using Query()**

```
  QueryParam = {
       TableName: 'YOUR TABLE NAME HERE',
       IndexName: 'YOUR INDEX NAME HERE', //IF YOUR CREATED NEW INDEX
       KeyConditionExpression: "UserId = :UserId  ", //YOUR PRIMARY KEY
       ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":UserId": UserId,
       },
       ScanIndexForward: false, //DESC ORDER, Set 'true' if u want asc order 
       ExclusiveStartKey: LastEvalVal, //Pagination - LastEvaluatedKeyPair
       Limit: 10 //DataPerReq
    }
```

Comment: Would this not search just a specific user? You would have to pass in a UserId here?

Comment: u must need to specify the Primary key to Query the Data from Table, u can changes primary key as some other fields and pass tat as param

Comment: ok thanks. Wont that only return values related to that primary key though? If Primary keys are unique you will only get one user record being returned? How would you return 10 different users using one primary key as the query?

Comment: yeah for that only you have to create a new Index in Table with different field as Primary Key  and query the Dynamo DB using that newly created Indexname.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The OP wants to return all rows. This answer is for returning a specific subset of all of the rows by a specific unique ID

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return *all* rows in your table, you cannot use the query API, because that API requires you to provide a partition key value to filter your results by (i.e. assuming that your partition key is `name` you would only be able to use the query API to bring back the subset of results that have `name` = a given value, i.e. `name= senthilkumar`

If you want to return *all* rows in your table, you must use the Scan API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Scan.html

Note that all results will be provided in ascending order by the value of the Range Key. **You cannot reverse sort the contents with the Scan API.** You would need to reverse your resultset in the application tier using whatever language you're writing your code in to turn the results upside down.

Scan does not scale well and **it is not possible to use Scan to create a paginated, reverse sorted solution** if your table contains items with unique partition keys.

If this is your situation, and if you want to return paginated + reverse sorted sets back from DynamoDB, you will need to re-consider the design of your table and which columns are the partition key/range key/index so that you can use the Query API.